# Classification of accelerometer data

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to classify accelerometer data into 4 classes- 1,2,3,4. The training dataset looks like the following-
[image]

The training labels are contained in another file and contain labels for only the 10th observation. This is what it looks like-
[image]

Now I am not sure how to interpret this. Should I only use the training_labels dataset to train a model? In that case, I don't know why the first dataset is given. Also, using only the second set would lead to a loss of information. I thought of doing a left-outer join on the first dataset with the second and using 'bfill' in df.fillna() to get rid of the Nan values and then use that data to train but I am confused as to whether this is the right approach. I am still a beginner at Machine Learning so any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** The data comes from an online course I am doing. It says that- "Because the accelerometers are sampled at high frequency, the labels in train_labels are only provided for every 10th observation

Comment: Where does your data come from? Maybe there's an explanation why there's a label only for every 10th observation. Or you can assume that the label stays constant for 10 observations, i.e. it changes at most every 10 timesteps. Maybe the sampling frequency was too high.

Comment: Yes, that's what the data description says that the accelerometers are sampled at high frequency. I added an 'Edit' to highlight this

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to discard 90% of your data you can just use only the observations with labels, you can also take the mean / median x,y,z coordinate of 10 observations with the provided label or use the same label for the for the last 10 observations.  Those approaches seem legit to me.

Probably the sampling frequency was unnecessary high and therefore you can assume labels do not change that quickly. But this can also depend on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

It is never too late to give a clue.

I agree about what Tinu has provided as answer. I would add the following:

You could do what he suggested to do only if the timestamp in the second array with labels is not provided. I would check if the timestamp elements of the second array are actually in the first array (the one you provided above). If so, perfect! Then I pick the corresponding value of accelerations, and voila!

Comment: This is more of a comment than an Answer.